# Can I go on a cruise from the UK to Scandinavia and St. Petersburg with a passport expiring in 4 months?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, passports, paperwork, russia

I have a passport expiring in September 2020. I will be traveling to the UK for a cruise to Scandinavia and St Petersburg in May. The cruise starts and ends in the UK.

Do I need to renew my passport before I go or am I safe?

Comment: In addition to the requirements of the countries you visit, you'll want to consider those of the cruise line.  They may have stricter requirements.  For Scandinavia, the passport must be valid for at least three months after you plan to leave.  I don't think the UK has a restriction beyond the expiration date. I don't know about Russia.

Comment: I think Russia may require passports to be valid for a minimum period of 6 months after the expiry date of your visa. You should check with the cruise line or your local Russian embassy/consulate.

Comment: What country issued the passport?

Comment: @Traveller Russian border control demands only that the passport be valid, so if holding a valid Russian visa, no problems

Comment: @phoog Do we know OP's nationality?

Comment: @Crazydre no. I assume it's an Annex II country. But being from an Annex I country would not change the passport validity requirement; it would only trigger a visa requirement.

Comment: @Crazydre While the OP doesn’t state their citizenship, both US travel advice https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/RussianFederation.html and Canadian https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/russia states that passports must be valid for 6 months beyond the expected date of leaving Russia. UK advice states the same. The question you’ve linked to in your answer deals with visas, it doesn’t mention passport validity as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not an EU/EFTA citizen or resident:

- For Scandinavia, the passport needs to be valid for 3 months beyond the period of intended stay (in the Schengen Area)
- [For Russia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3040/18374), the passport just needs to be valid during the stay.

So no, contrary to the other answer, no need to renew your passport.

Comment: Note that, if the OP is a UK citizen, then they still have EU free movement until 31 Dec 2020. This is part of the Brexit transitional arrangements. The UK issued passports with upto 10 years, 9 months validity - I'm not sure when the EU will stop recognizing  the extra to 9 months of validity, or if Russia ever recognized this

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the type of cruise. In particular for the port of St. Petersburg, passengers of cruise ships are not required to have an entry visa into Russia for up to 72 hours, but only in case they have officially booked tours with licensed tour providers. Therefore, the validity of passport is not important.

[information on visa-free entry in Russia](https://www.russiavisa.com/visafreeentry.htm)

Not sure about passport requirements for Scandinavian countries.

Answer (score -4):

Most countries in Europe (Schengen specifically) require that your passport be valid for at least 6 months before entry.

However, this is NOT the case with the UK. They just require that your passport be valid for the entire duration of your stay.

However, when entering Scandinavia, you’ll need at least 6 months validity, so yes you will need to renew it.

Comment: The Schengen requirement is for the passport to be valid for three months after the anticipated date of departure, not six months from the date of entry.  If the cruise finishes in May, there should be no problem with Scandinavia.